# jquery mobile header issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, header

I have a issue with my jquery mobile header.

I include 2 photo link.

[Image 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7sb24il6ygj5cfn/2.png)

[Image 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmy0njl49z1gab7/3.png)

Image 1: I tap in the textarea and de app slide down and the keyboard pops up. So far so good.

Image 2: If I'm done typing I hit the button 'verstuur' (dutch for send) then the keyboard disappears and my header is moving to the middle.

i have this line of code for my header

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
  <a href="#mypanel" data-theme="reset" data-icon="menubars" data-iconpos="notext">Navigation</a>
    <h1>Melding</h1>
  <a onClick="RefeshPagina()" data-theme="reset" data-icon="reload" data-iconpos="notext">Reload</a>
</div>
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

One of my application i used

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" style="font-family:verdana">
    <h1>Test app</h1>
    <% if SyncEngine::logged_in > 0 %>
      <a href="<%= url_for :controller => :Settings, :action => :do_sync %>" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="refresh">
        Sync
      </a>
      <a href="<%= url_for :controller => :Settings, :action => :logout %>" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="star">
        Logout
      </a>
    <% else %>
          <!-- <a href="<%= url_for :controller => :Settings, :action => :login %>" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="star">Login</a>  -->
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Working fine for me. I used `jquery.mobile-1.0.1`

Note: On your second link u didn't mention the `href`. If you don't want to mention the correct link `href` please mention it as `<a href="#"> ... </a>`

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to your header bar and try this script.

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#your_header").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });
});
```